# ckeditore show data from mysql with ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, ckeditor

I can't load data in **CK editor** from *MySQL* database with *Ajax*.

This is my `code` :

```
<script>
  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );

  function loadSlideDate() {
    $.ajax('<?php echo baseUrl()?>/admin/loadDateSlides', {
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#name1").val(data[0].title)
            $("#description1").val(data[0].description)
            $("#name2").val(data[1].title)
            $("#description2").val(data[1].description)
            $("#name3").val(data[2].title)
            $("#editor1").val(data[2].description)
        },
    });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Try to add some more info, like what's the error you may be facing?

Comment: Can you add some Error message, please?

Comment: The problem is that data, the database should be displayed in the editor does not show

Comment: editor better for woke :https://www.tinymce.com/download/